# Полное удаление строки из SQL

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Как мне удалить всю строку из SQL Таблицы?
Следующим запросом он удаляет только данные из этой строки, а не всю строку.

```
if($query="del")
{
$do="DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$table.".id=".$id."";
@mysql_query($do, $mv);
}
```

P.S. Если Удалять тем же запросом через phpMyAdmin то все получается...

Comment: mysql_error() после mysql_query() что выводит?

Comment: т.е. если выполнить этот запрос с `$id = 15`, у вас в базе остается строка с `id = 15`, но без данных?

Comment: @igolka97, PhpMyAdmin при выполнении запросов обычно пишет какие именно запросы он выполнил. Можно скопировать их оттуда.

Comment: странно, должна удаляться полностью строка. ничего не путаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если table у вас - название таблицы. А ID - это ID строки для уаления, то просто

```
DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE id=".$id.";
```

Comment: меня всегда интересовало в java есть механизм prepared statement. напр можно спарсить запрос вида `"select * from some_table where id = ?"`; а потом вызывать его сколько угодно раз подставляя параметры помеченые знаком "?". в php нет чего-то подобного?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, "сколько угодно раз" не обращаясь к БД - не, такого вроде нет. Разве что вытянуть все, а потом просто обращаться к масиву по нужному ключу.

Comment: 2 @jmu во многих фреймворках существует подобный механизм :)

Comment: @jmu, в MySQL есть поддержка prepared statements. Я использую для работы с этим PDO.